# space between old price in magento

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to delete the space that is between a field and the price of a product in magento. For example, if there is a special price, everything is fine: the div is organized good with the other elements, but if there is no special price, then it is a big space (where the special price should be) between the old price adn the random field lets say. I didn't override any magento templates, so don't know where to start.

Any suggestion? Would really appreciate.

Comment: if you are not using any theme or customization create new theme for customization and copy file from app\design\frontend\base\default\template\catalog\product\price.phtml to your theme and customized according to your requirements

Comment: Ok, I have some troubles with the ifs, very complicated template. Just one question, do you think it's possible to check somewhere if the div contains the special price, otherwise to not show? @faizanbeg

Comment: yes you can check in the template file first check above mentioned file not override, to do this go to file there is main div class name "price-box" add new class in this div and refresh cache then reload page for special price there is p having class "special-price"